# Hiding/Showing SherlockFragments in ActionBar.TabListener Class, content is empty

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have an app built using TabBarSherlock and the Support library to add ActionBar support to pre 3.0 devices. I can't remember what tutorial I followed to create the Tabs and the Listener but I have the following code.

**Firstly creating the Tabs (Inside a SherlockFragmentActivity):**

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

/*--------Setup News Tab--------*/
Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText("News")
        .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabFragment>(
                        this, "tab1", TabFragment.class));
Bundle newsBundle = new Bundle();
newsBundle.putInt("news_id", newsID);
tab1.setTag(newsBundle);
actionBar.addTab(tab1);
/*------------------------------*/
// This is repeated 3 more times to total 4 Tabs.
```

**Then I have a classCalled `TabListener` which is used in each of these Tabs to detect when they have been selected.**

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    private TabFragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialised
        if (mFragment == null) {
             Log.v("FRAGMENT", "FRAGMENT NEEDS TO BE CREATED");
             mFragment = (TabFragment) Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), (Bundle)tab.getTag());
             ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            Log.v("FRAGMENT", "FRAGMENT ALREADY CREATED");
            ft.show(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.hide(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

With the class `TabFragment` containing a `ViewPager` for each Tab. My issue is that when selecting a Tab other than the first one the content inside the Fragment does not show. From the logs in place when the Fragment is initialised I can tell the views are being created just not being shown, it's just a blank area showing the background.

Comment: It could be helpful to see your `TabFragment` class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `show()` and `hide()`, use `attach()` and `detach()`. Using show/hide does not remove the view hierarchy from the screen, simply hides it, so there might be issues related to that.

Comment: I want it to only show and hide that's the point. Detach and Attach cause it to have to re create all images in the fragment which in my case is very intense on the memory and causes visible lag.

Comment: Does that work though @SamRowley? Then we can at least identify show/hide as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not detaching fragment rather you are just hiding it. so you should detach it so that other fragment should be attached in your `onTabUnSelected`.

`FragmentManager` will automatically restore whatever fragment (and history) was currently displayed upon a configuration change. Call `findFragmentByTag` to see if an instance of the target fragment already exists before creating and attaching a new instance.

Example:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (mFragment == null && preInitializedFragment == null) {
        // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
        mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else if (mFragment != null) {
        // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    } else if (preInitializedFragment != null) {
        ft.attach(preInitializedFragment);
        mFragment = preInitializedFragment;
    }
}
```

and you `onTabUnSelected` should be like this

```
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Content is empty on tab bar then write below code 
`final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);`